# Python requests request leads to 400 error while cURL request is OK

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests, yandex

I use requests as following:

```
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.__yandex_cloud_manager.get_iam_token().token}',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    }

    data = {
        'voice': self.voice,
        'emotion': 'neutral',
        'lang': self.language,
        'speed': self.temp,
        'folderId': self.__get_folder_id(),
        'format': 'oggopus',
        'text': text,
    }

    response = requests.post(
            url='https://tts.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/tts:synthesize',
            headers=headers,
            data=data)
```

It sends this data:

```
send: b'POST /speech/v1/tts:synthesize HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: tts.api.cloud.yandex.net\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAuthorization: Bearer <removed>\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nContent-Length: 135\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n'
send: b'voice=alyss&emotion=neutral&lang=ru-RU&speed=1.0&folderId=<removed>&format=oggopus&text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82'
```

And I get 400 response.

But when I dump request like this:

```
            req = response.request

            command = "curl -X {method} -H {headers} -d '{data}' '{uri}'"
            method = req.method
            uri = req.url
            data = req.body
            headers = ['"{0}: {1}"'.format(k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()]
            headers = " -H ".join(headers)
            print(command.format(method=method, headers=headers, data=data, uri=uri))
```

It gives the following command:

```
curl -X POST -H "User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Authorization: Bearer <removed>" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -H "Content-Length: 135" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'voice=alyss&emotion=neutral&lang=ru-RU&speed=1.0&folderId=<removed>&format=oggopus&text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82' 'https://tts.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/tts:synthesize'
```

And request with this command executes successfully.

What could be wroing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it works if I remove `"Transfer-Encoding: chunked"` header.

Comment: That's because you shouldn't be setting that header. Requests usually controls that but if you tell it otherwise, it lets you shoot yourself in the foot by sending garbage. Garbage in, garbage out